# IE 11 Ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

So internet explorer does it again. I currently have a `validation.php` file where values in a text box are sent for validation. The text-box value is read and then a result is given to say if this is valid or not. This works perfectly on any other browser but IE. The ajax request specifically doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. The script below is in charge of taking the data from the input-box and sending the request via AJAX.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#email").blur(function () {
      var username = $(this).val();
      if (username == '') {
        $("#availability").html("Empty Input");
      }
      else{
        $.ajax({
          url: "validation.php?uname="+username
        }).done(function( data ) {
        if (data.includes("result-from-validation")){
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
        else {
         // DISPLAY ERROR
        } 
        });   
      } 
    });
  });
```

Comment: you did not specify method specify it other wiser print_r($_REQUEST)

Comment: There's nothing there that wouldn't work on IE if it works in other browsers. Are you getting any specific errors? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Styphon your statement is not absolutely true. You may want to tune your wording.

Comment: Look at your console. I'm sure you'll see something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `username` really, really should be URI-encoded before being sent as part of a URI: `url: "validation.php?uname="+encodeURIComponent(username)` (or let jQuery do it by passing as `data: {uname: username}`).
2. [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) are both new things in JavaScript. It's no surprise that an older browser doesn't have them.

   Both can be polyfilled if desired (see links above), or you can probably use `indexOf`: `if (data.indexOf("result-from-validation") != -1)`

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was the 'Array#includes' that was an issue. Have added the encoding as well. Much appreciated